# How to add existing normal partition into LVM in Linux?

Tags: lvm

I'm having a partition in Linux with some data, I want to add this partition into LVM, which is already running in the same system.

What will be the step to do so?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot simply add existing non-LVM partitions into LVM. You'll have to create a partition within LVM and then migrate the data that's on the non-LVM partition into this newly created LVM partition. For this work you'll likely be using `cp` or `rsync` to do the migration once the partition is set up.

This tutorial titled: [Weekend Project: Migrate from Direct Partitions to LVM Volumes](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/306352-weekend-project-migrate-from-direct-partitions-to-lvm-volumes) explains how to go about setting up LVM and towards the end, describes various methods for copying the data from the physical partition to the LVM partition.

Comment: Oh, but you could try. :-)  Reduce the filesystem size, move it 384K off the beginning of the partition... If you force LVM to use this PV for a new LV (e.g. by allocation all the rest for a tmp LV before) then that may work... ;-)

Comment: @HaukeLaging No, it isn't going to work. You'd have to get the data into the LVM extents, in the right order. You'd just end up trashing the data.

Comment: @Gilles Right but extents are allocated in order.